# Run websocket server remotely or on my server (not proxy)

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

So here http://socketo.me/docs/troubleshooting is said:

"If you want to open Ratchet up (not behind a proxy) set the third parameter of App to '0.0.0.0'."

I did it here (/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/App.php):

```
     /**
     * @param string        $httpHost HTTP hostname clients intend to connect to. MUST match JS `new WebSocket('ws://$httpHost');`
     * @param int           $port     Port to listen on. If 80, assuming production, Flash on 843 otherwise expecting Flash to be proxied through 8843
     * @param string        $address  IP address to bind to. Default is localhost/proxy only. '0.0.0.0' for any machine.
     * @param LoopInterface $loop     Specific React\EventLoop to bind the application to. null will create one for you.
     */   
    public function __construct($httpHost = '47.243.247.244', $port = 8180, $address = '0.0.0.0', LoopInterface $loop = null) {
```

This is my client side:

```
var websocket_server = new WebSocket("ws://47.243.247.244:8180/");
```

And this is websocket server:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())),
    8180
);
```

My problem is that I can't connect on client side. Can you correct me what did I do wrong? I searched it in Intrenet but couldn't fid clear answer. And please, don't show me how to do it with proxy. (For security I showed you different ip address of my site)

Comment: Maybe your server's firewall is not configured to allow incoming traffic on port 8180?

Comment: I did talk to support from my hosting and they said there is not firewall on this port